# jqGrid not showing rows

Tags: json, jqgrid

I am getting the response Json :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">{"records":"830","page":1,"total":42,"rows":[{"Guid":"0565bbfe-3533-42ee-b935-4cf491399994","group_name":"Chart Of The Week","Name":"UK house prices and GDP","ChartOwner":"ADMIN","pathname":"Datastream\\Charts from Alpha Now\\Chart Of The Week\\|-3,45571,100060,"},{"Guid":"65fea74c-0125-46b2-a618-6cf5b7abf162","group_name":"Residential Sector","Name":"Weekly Residential GFA Sold in Guiyang","ChartOwner":"ADMIN","pathname":"Datastream\\Real Estate Markets\\_Real Estate Foresight\\Residential Sector\\|-3,58585,97205,100070,"},{"Guid":"21f8c6dd-3437-4517-a532-457c09c1d80f","group_name":"Residential Sector","Name":"Weekly Residential GFA Sold in Shaoguan","ChartOwner":"ADMIN","pathname":"Datastream\\Real Estate Markets\\_Real Estate Foresight\\Residential Sector\\|-3,58585,97205,100070,"},{"Guid":"45c82732-54a0-4e93-bb07-30099a07fe3f","group_name":"Residential Sector","Name":"Weekly Residential GFA Sold in Shaoxin","ChartOwner":"ADMIN","pathname":"Datastream\\Real Estate Markets\\_Real Estate Foresight\\Residential Sector\\|-3,58585,97205,100070,"},{"Guid":"074731f2-7578-457c-89e9-14a3b09b67c3","group_name":"Residential Sector","Name":"Weekly Residential GFA Sold in Shenyang","ChartOwner":"ADMIN","pathname":"Datastream\\Real Estate Markets\\_Real Estate Foresight\\Residential Sector\\|-3,58585,97205,100070,"},{"Guid":"c287c938-4f87-4319-a1ed-a015d1690742","group_name":"Residential Sector","Name":"Weekly Residential GFA Sold in Suzhou","ChartOwner":"ADMIN","pathname":"Datastream\\Real Estate Markets\\_Real Estate Foresight\\Residential Sector\\|-3,58585,97205,100070,"},{"Guid":"10a1af78-32d8-4306-bff2-1d44ea8a6b0e","group_name":"Residential Sector","Name":"Weekly Residential GFA Sold in Tianjin","ChartOwner":"ADMIN","pathname":"Datastream\\Real Estate Markets\\_Real Estate Foresight\\Residential Sector\\|-3,58585,97205,100070,"},{"Guid":"4fe34cd4-cf3d-4343-9de3-9b1467f73025","group_name":"Residential Sector","Name":"Weekly Residential GFA Sold in Wenzhou","ChartOwner":"ADMIN","pathname":"Datastream\\Real Estate Markets\\_Real Estate Foresight\\Residential Sector\\|-3,58585,97205,100070,"},{"Guid":"b5afa485-1bac-4cd3-8ebc-54d1eb82b9f0","group_name":"Residential Sector","Name":"Weekly Residential GFA Sold in Wuhan","ChartOwner":"ADMIN","pathname":"Datastream\\Real Estate Markets\\_Real Estate Foresight\\Residential Sector\\|-3,58585,97205,100070,"},{"Guid":"63d560e8-2f8f-436d-b150-a4b35b404452","group_name":"Residential Sector","Name":"Weekly Residential GFA Sold in Xiamen","ChartOwner":"ADMIN","pathname":"Datastream\\Real Estate Markets\\_Real Estate Foresight\\Residential Sector\\|-3,58585,97205,100070,"},{"Guid":"87b51f8e-0b8b-488b-8fa7-8dad1a6d60d3","group_name":"Residential Sector","Name":"Weekly Residential GFA Sold in Xi'an","ChartOwner":"ADMIN","pathname":"Datastream\\Real Estate Markets\\_Real Estate Foresight\\Residential Sector\\|-3,58585,97205,100070,"},{"Guid":"0b8904cf-948f-43c9-ad10-53eb5334b41d","group_name":"Residential Sector","Name":"Weekly Residential GFA Sold in Wuxi","ChartOwner":"ADMIN","pathname":"Datastream\\Real Estate Markets\\_Real Estate Foresight\\Residential Sector\\|-3,58585,97205,100070,"},{"Guid":"795b7370-36c8-47cf-a682-2d5118898a60","group_name":"Residential Sector","Name":"Average House Price in Beijing and Y/Y Change","ChartOwner":"ADMIN","pathname":"Datastream\\Real Estate Markets\\_Real Estate Foresight\\Residential Sector\\|-3,58585,97205,100070,"},{"Guid":"d35706ec-71be-4551-8073-0aed4a02da52","group_name":"Residential Sector","Name":"Average House Price in Chongqing and Y/Y Change","ChartOwner":"ADMIN","pathname":"Datastream\\Real Estate Markets\\_Real Estate Foresight\\Residential Sector\\|-3,58585,97205,100070,"},{"Guid":"5d6414c6-c3c5-4343-9e5d-35359849d28e","group_name":"Residential Sector","Name":"Average House Price in Guangzhou and Y/Y Change","ChartOwner":"ADMIN","pathname":"Datastream\\Real Estate Markets\\_Real Estate Foresight\\Residential Sector\\|-3,58585,97205,100070,"},{"Guid":"67f6b3f8-1b74-4292-8a5f-fb41529e2640","group_name":"Residential Sector","Name":"Average House Price in Hangzhou and Y/Y Change","ChartOwner":"ADMIN","pathname":"Datastream\\Real Estate Markets\\_Real Estate Foresight\\Residential Sector\\|-3,58585,97205,100070,"},{"Guid":"0f229364-e553-4aa9-954d-deee7796a578","group_name":"Residential Sector","Name":"Average House Price in Nanjing and Y/Y Change","ChartOwner":"ADMIN","pathname":"Datastream\\Real Estate Markets\\_Real Estate Foresight\\Residential Sector\\|-3,58585,97205,100070,"},{"Guid":"bb6abe38-2ac1-442b-a718-c0ab199e7bc2","group_name":"Residential Sector","Name":"Average House Price in Shanghai and Y/Y Change","ChartOwner":"ADMIN","pathname":"Datastream\\Real Estate Markets\\_Real Estate Foresight\\Residential Sector\\|-3,58585,97205,100070,"},{"Guid":"0a195ca1-e1fe-4a4a-939e-792cf979d4bb","group_name":"Residential Sector","Name":"Average House Price in Shenzhen and Y/Y Change","ChartOwner":"ADMIN","pathname":"Datastream\\Real Estate Markets\\_Real Estate Foresight\\Residential Sector\\|-3,58585,97205,100070,"},{"Guid":"ee6ee3a9-0306-4611-b700-1cd74870bb72","group_name":"Residential Sector","Name":"Average House Price in Xiamen and Y/Y Change","ChartOwner":"ADMIN","pathname":"Datastream\\Real Estate Markets\\_Real Estate Foresight\\Residential Sector\\|-3,58585,97205,100070,"}]}</string>
```

And, my jqGrid code as shown below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
                url: 'LibraryWebService.asmx/GetCharts',
                mtype: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                colModel: [
                    { label: 'Guid', name: 'Guid', key: true, width: 75 },
                    { label: 'group_name', name: 'group_name', width: 100 },
                    { label: 'Name', name: 'Name', width: 150 },
                    { label: 'ChartOwner', name: 'ChartOwner', width: 75 },
                    { label: 'pathname', name: 'pathname', width: 250 }
                ],
                page: 1,
                width: 780,
                height: 250,
                rowNum: 20,
                multiselect: true,
                scrollPopUp: true,
                scrollLeftOffset: "83%",
                viewrecords: true,
                gridview: true,
                loadonce: true,

                scroll: 1, // set the scroll property to 1 to enable paging with scrollbar - virtual loading of records
                emptyrecords: 'Scroll to bottom to retrieve new page', // the message will be displayed at the bottom 
                pager: "#jqGridPager"
            });
            $("#getselected").click(function () {
                var sr = $("#jqGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow');
                if (sr.length) {
                    alert(sr.join());
                } else {
                    alert("no charts are selected!");
                }
            });
        });
```

Grid is not showing. 
When I remove scroll=1 property, I am seeing the empty grid and the pager as: Page 1 of 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can see that "the response Json" is XML and no JSON. You should change the server part of your code to return no XML wrapper.

It's important to understand additionally that ASMX method should return `object` instead of `string`. You don't need do any manual conversion of object to JSON string. The conversion do ASP.NET for you automatically to XML or JSON based on the information from `Accept` HTTP header of the request.

Moreover you should probably replace **non-existing option** `dataType: 'json'` and `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' to`datatype: 'json'`and`ajaxGridOptions: {contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}`.

I would recommend you remove `scroll: 1` option and use standard paging.

If you use `loadonce: true` option then you can skip `"records":"830","page":1,"total":42,"rows"` part in the server response. Instead of that you can just return **all** 830 records as array of items (the value of `rows` property from the current response).